# how to use __str__ with foreign key '__str__ returned non-string (type Product)'

Tags: python, django, model

while i try to

```
__str__()
```

method for a foreign it provide this error

```
__str__ returned non-string (type Product)
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50 , 
    blank=False,null=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
class ProductOrder(models.Model):


    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE , 
    null=True)
    ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    pass 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

i also tried this

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name 

#product_name is a field from Product table
```

the error will provide is

```
__str__ returned non-string (type QuerySet)
```

how to represent it , thanks for reply !

Comment: Can you share your `Product` model?

Comment: Try `str(self.product)` or `str(self.product.product_name)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated

Comment: @jfaccioni i tried both , didnt work

Comment: @namo: can you return the exact traceback? Are you sure the error is not in *another* `__str__` method?

Comment: other working fine , but the problem is with __str__ in productorder model

Comment: @namo: if you use `str(self.product)`, and you rerun the project, can you share the traceback you *then* obtain. Perhaps then the error is located somewhere else.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/04TVVZS its the traceback

Comment: Please show your `Order` model and `__str__` method

Comment: @namo: at first sight it looks like there is another model that has a `__str__` that does not return a string, probably the `Order`, since that is the other `ForeignKey` in your `ProductOrder`.

Comment: exactly i forget it , much appreciate

Comment: but in the template just return the ID of the product instead of the name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not return something other than a `str`ing from the `__str__` method. `self.product` is not a `str`ing, but a `Product` object.

You can however call `str(..)` over it, to get the textual representation of that `Product`:

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

Comment: i also tried it but doesnt work (__str__ returned non-string (type QuerySet)
)

Comment: Then something really bizarre is going on. Are you sure you wrote `self.product` (not `product`). Can you share your `Product` model, perhaps something is defined in such way that somehow it returns a `QuerySet`?

Comment: how to show foreign key instead of its id in the template

Comment: @namo: usually if you use `{{ some_object.foreign_key }}` it will fetch the related object, and thus use the `__str__` of the object to which is referred. But if you of course specified a `__str__` that returns the `str(self.pk)` that is the primary key. I suggest that you ask a new question with the relevant template, model(s) and view.

Answer (score 3):

that because `models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE , 
    null=True)` is not returning a `str` so return a string for that function or try to do

```
return str(self.product)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```py
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.product)
```

Also you may need to define the `__str__` method on your `Product` model

Comment: Then I guess your Product model is not correctly set. Maybe you have defined somewhere in your file a Product variable which override your model definition somehow ? It shouldn't be a queryset. What is the __str__ method of your Product model ?

Comment: i updated the code , and shared the Product model too ,

Answer (score 0):

**ForeignKey** returns whole linked base connected to Key. You need to return **CharFeiled** from **ProductOrder** or stiring like **self.product.product_name** from other class.

Answer (score 0):

i face the same problem .
i resolve it.
the code is

```
     def __str__(self):
     return self.product.product_name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).